# image.save() not saving file with specified name

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

using following code to save all tiffs to a single PDF

```
from PIL import Image
imagelist[0].save(fp=path_to_saving_location+"specified_name.pdf",save_all =True, append_images = imagelist[1:])
```

instead it is saving the PDF as 001.pdf.
Am I doing anything wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable called `fullpath` in the line above the `save` statement and set its value how you think.

Print it so you can check it. Then use:

```
imagelist[0].save(fullpath, save_all =True, append_images = imagelist[1:])
```

Also, consider deleting `001.pdf` before you run your program, so you can be sure if your program really does create it.